# Entity Framework 7 In memory test with interceptor

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I've decided to try a new [interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#simple-actions-on-entity-creation) that comes with Entity Framework 7.
So in OnConfiguring method in DbContext I've added.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(new MaterializationInterceptor());
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting error in my test that use in memory db.

> A call was made to 'AddInterceptors', but Entity Framework is not building its own internal service provider. Either allow Entity Framework to build the service provider by removing the call to 'UseInternalServiceProvider', or build the 'ISingletonInterceptor' services to use into the service provider before passing it to 'UseInternalServiceProvider'.

This is how I'm trying to register dbContext in my test

```
public void Register(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
        .AddSingleton<ISingletonInterceptor, MaterializationInterceptor>()
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    services.AddDbContext<TDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseInMemoryDatabase(_inMemoryDbIdentifier.DatabaseName, _inMemoryDbIdentifier.InMemoryDatabaseRoot);
        options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
    });
}
```

I've alse try to add interceptor by calling option.AddInterceptor but still got this error

```
services.AddDbContext<TDbContext>(options => options.AddInterceptors(new MaterializationInterceptor())
```

I don't know how else I could build the ISingletonInterceptor services.
Thank you for any answers

Comment: Why so complicated? Why do not add interceptor exactly when you register context, I mean `services.AddDbContext<TDbContext>(options => .... .AddInterceptors(new MaterializationInterceptor())`.

Comment: I've tried that and still got this error

Comment: Can you try it with Sqlite provider? In-Memory provider is like a fake and is not recommended for testing.

Comment: Also remove `options.UseInternalServiceProvider`

Comment: Just made [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78155389/10646316) how to make interceptor and it works.

Comment: Thank you @SvyatoslavDanyliv I will try to use Sqllite. And I have to use `options.UseInternalServiceProvider`