# How can I break in the debugger when I am, using Entity Framework, querying a model from my code?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I need to break into the debugger when anywhere in my code it is making a query to the database. Are there some method(s) I can override in my `DbContext` where I just call the base class, but I can put a breakpoint there. And I will then break on any query of the DB?

And/or is there another way to accomplish this?

And to emphasize, I need to break on reading in data. I do have a `SaveChangesAsync()` override that I use to break on creates/updates/deletes.

Comment: Use right tags, `[entity-framework]` is wrong tag for EF Core.

Comment: Check out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IQueryExpressionInterceptor`. Create something simple and put breakpoint into interceptor code:

```cs
public class QueryExpressionFakeInterceptor : IQueryExpressionInterceptor
{
    public static QueryExpressionFakeInterceptor Default = new QueryExpressionFakeInterceptor();

    public Expression QueryCompilationStarting(Expression queryExpression, QueryExpressionEventData eventData)
    {
        return queryExpression; // put breakpoint here
    }
}
```

And register interceptor:

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString) // or any other provider
    .AddInterceptors(QueryExpressionFakeInterceptor.Default);
```

This solution will work for any query, `ExecuteUpdate` and `ExecuteDelete`.

Comment: Question, is there any property in `Expression` or `QueryExpression` that has the original query from my call? I can sort-of figure out where each is coming from, but it would be a lot easier if I could view the original query. TIA

Comment: You can look at callback up and find your original query. `queryExpression` is your original query, without `ToList`, `ToArray`, etc. Try to use `ExpressionPrinter` from EF Core's `Internal` namespace to uncover expression.